# Why does OCaml have two sorting functions: List.sort and List.stable_sort?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

here are the doc:

---

```
val sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

Sort a list in increasing order according to a comparison function. The comparison function must return 0 if its arguments compare as equal, a positive integer if the first is greater, and a negative integer if the first is smaller (see Array.sort for a complete specification). For example, compare is a suitable comparison function. The resulting list is sorted in increasing order. List.sort is guaranteed to run in constant heap space (in addition to the size of the result list) and logarithmic stack space.

The current implementation uses Merge Sort. It runs in constant heap space and logarithmic stack space.

```
val stable_sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

Same as List.sort, but `the sorting algorithm is guaranteed to be stable` (i.e. elements that compare equal are kept in their original order) .

The current implementation uses Merge Sort. It runs in constant heap space and logarithmic stack space.

---

I thought `merge sort` anyway is stable, right?

How can OCaml produce a `non-stable merge` sort?

In the `non-statble merge sort` version, is it faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merge sort is stable, but the fact that sort uses merge sort is not part of its contract. Note that it only says "the current implementation uses...". There is no guarantee that it will keep using merge sort in the future, so if you use `List.sort` in your code there is no guarantee that the sort will be stable even if it might happen to be stable in the current implementation.

As long as every code that requires a stable sort uses `stable_sort`, no code will break if future versions (or alternative implementations) of Ocaml switch to an unstable algorithm for `sort`.

Comment: ahh, ok, it is like a doc thing, i.e., they wrote the doc in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the definition from the implementation. The implementors are reserving the right to change the implementation, and are being admirably careful and clear about how the functions are defined to behave.

Comment: You can see an example on how to use the library List.sort [94; 50; 6; 7; 8];; Should I add a question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755939/sorting-list-with-ocaml-standard-library-function