# Sorting List with OCaml standard library function

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm studying OCaml and and doing various exercises on ordering data.
I would like to understand how to use the standard librari List for ordering

For example I would like to sort this array using these functions [94; 50; 6; 7; 8; 8]

```
List.sort 
List.stable_sort 
List.fast_sort 
List.unique_sort
```

What is the syntax to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use these functions on your list, you have to specifiy the comparison function.

Quote from the documentation:

> The comparison function must return 0 if its arguments compare as
>   equal, a positive integer if the first is greater, and a negative
>   integer if the first is smaller

In the module `Pervasives` you have a polymorphic comparison function:

```
val compare : 'a -> 'a -> int
```

So, in your case you can just do:

```
List.sort compare [94; 50; 6; 7; 8; 8]
```

Comment: You can also add the descending sort with compare function?

Comment: Perfect:-) for descending "let myCompare x y = if x<y then 1 else -1;;"  I missed this step. thanks

Comment: That will mostly work, but `myCompare 1 1` will return `-1`. You can always do, `(fun x y -> ~- (compare x y))`.